# Change CartoDB map with new center

Tags: javascript, carto

So I already have the code working to initiate a map and to populate it with data points with a dynamic slider. What I am trying to do now is to have a user type in a query and when they submit that query, the map changes its center lat,lng to the new one.

So it'll pretty much be like

- Search Rutgers Club
- Get Lat & Lon
- Change map center to new Lat & Lon

You can access my live site at [parkru.com/v2.html](http://parkru.com/v2.html)

Also, [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3516bda53dfa41ce49f4) is what my js file looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be a combination of the SQL API inside of CartoDB.js and the Google Maps panTo function. Also see here,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874576/google-maps-pan-to

```
var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'cartodb_user' });
var interesting_id = 3; 
sql.execute("SELECT ST_Y(ST_Center(the_geom)) lat, ST_X(ST_Center(the_geom)) lon FROM table_name WHERE id > {{id}}", { id: interesting_id })
  .done(function(data) {
         // create a new point from the returned lat/lon
         var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.rows[0].lat, data.rows[0].lon);
         map.panTo(latLng);
   })
```

If you wanted to do the same thing in Leaflet, it would be almost identical except for how you create the point,

```
var latLng = new L.LatLng(data.rows[0].lat, data.rows[0].lon);
```

If you don't know where the `map` var comes from, take a look here, https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/doc/API.md#visgetnativemap